# How can I merge and add values in a column of csv if all the other columns are same?

Tags: excel, csv

I have a csv file where I am having multiple columns. First n columns are string and last (n+1)th column is an integer. I want to merge all the rows where first n columns are same and put the added value in (n+1)th column.

Example

Input:

1. A1          B1              C1          3
2. A2          B2              C2          2
3. A3          B3              C3          1
4. A1          B1              C1          2
5. A2          B2              C2          -1

Output:

1. A1          B1              C1          5
2. A2          B2              C2          1
3. A3          B3              C3          1

Comment: can you write an example of your csv and what you want?

Comment: @kraysak Added example in question description now.

Comment: @pnuts Because my data was in CSV format and I am happy if I get some other scripts to do my work without excel also.

Answer (score 0):

First, let me paraphrase to make sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish:

- You have n columns with each row containing a string and one column with each row containing an integer
- You want to have a list of unique combinations of the n columns and the sum of the integers corresponding to each instance of a unique combination.
- Assumption: order matters in the columns (i.e., A1: Hello, A2: World is not the same as A1: World, A2: Hello).

There are a number of ways to go about this, but here's one idea:

Add another column, concatenating the n strings:

```
=CONCATENATE(A1,B1,C1) //assuming that A through C are your string columns
```

Then create a pivot table where your row labels are the values in the concatenated field and your values are the sums of the integer column.

To create a pivot table, first make sure that your columns are labeled at the top of the row, then highlight the entire range of data, go to Insert then PivotTable. Then click OK and drag the fields into the areas you want them to go into on the righthand side in the field list.

Here's an example: [example.xlsx](https://s3.amazonaws.com/nflees/example.xlsx)

As an alternative to the pivot table, you could copy all the concatenated strings, remove duplicates, and do a SUMIF.

Comment: Your all the assumptions are correct. But I am sorry I am new to excel, can you please explain the part after concatenation?

Answer (score 0):

Work on a copy.

Your output may be reached from your input as below:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A1,B:B,B1,C:C,C1)
```

in Row1 and copied down to suit. Copy formulae and Paste Special, Values over the top. Delete the preexisting integers. Select all relevant columns and Remove Duplicates.

The formula in practice would need to be extended to include all `n` columns and D:D would be the (n+1)th.